# Bash sed convert string to int or float

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a string that I have to convert into int or float depending or the case :

```
What I have    => What I want
"548189848.54" => "548189848.54"
"548189848.50" => "548189848.5"
"548189848.00" => "548189848"
"0.0000"       => "0"
```

How can I do it using sed ?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Why don't use a programming language like C or Python?

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Because he wants to (or is required to) use a programming language like `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Because it's easier in `sed`.

Comment: Really I didn't know sed could do that..I just knew this is possoble in `awk`. That's why I edited question with tag `awk`

Comment: So all you really want is to strip trailing zeros, possibly preceded by a decimal point, but only if the string contains a decimal point (i.e. you don't want "1000" to become "1"...)? Have you tried anything? That seems fairly straightforward...

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with two `sed` expressions, one for trailing zeroes after the dot, the other for those after a non-zero digit. They are quite different, as in the former case you have to remove the dot as well.

This solution works with any number of erm... numbers on the same line and does NOT remove trailing zeroes from integers, as that would change the value.

I'm using the GNU-only `-r` regex dialect.

```
sed -r -e 's/([0-9]+)\.0+\b/\1/g' -e 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+\b/\1/g'
```

or

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+)\.0+\b/\1/g;s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+\b/\1/g'
```

The first regex explained:

- one or more digits, captured as \1 with parens
- dot
- one or more zeroes
- word boundary
- replace with 1st capture group \1

The second regex explained

- one or more digits
- dot
- zero or more digits
- one nonzero digit
- everything captured up to this point as \1 with parens
- one ore more zeroes
- word boundary
- replace with 1st capture group \1

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat file
548189848.54
548189848.50
548189848.00
0.0000
```

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\.?0+$/,"")}1' file
548189848.54
548189848.5
548189848
0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\.0+|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+)\b/\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$YourString" | sed 's/0*$"//;s/[.]$//'
```

Assuming there is no number without decimal part